# Finding records which match a sequential sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want my query to show me records which don't have a sequential sequence. For example, I have a table of bank installments and they have an instalmentID assigned to them.

The records should be in order, eg of instalmentIDs and value:

```
5 £10
4 £10
3 £10
2 £10
1 £10
```

My data have records which look like this:

```
-2 £10
-1 £10
0  £10
1  £10
```

The above are examples of *bad* installments.

I could write the following:

```
SELECT ORDERID
FROM INSTALMENTS
WHERE INSTALMENTID = 0
```

But i need to see the results returned in the corrected format so that i cabn populate a temp table and run some updates. So my query needs to know if the last good sequence was 1 then it needs to change `0, -1, -2` to `2,3,4`

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you are trying to do. { -2, -1, 0, 1 } *is* in ascending sequential order, { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } is in descending sequential order. Where is OrderID in the sample data?

Comment: Agreed with Rhys, it's unclear how you want to actually evaluate this information.  You mention the "last good" sequence, but with the data you provided it looks like "last good" is the smallest positive integer greater than 0.  If you have another column like a datetime or an identity that is auto-incremented, you can then iterate through the set and either change the values or use them as is.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is that issue arises because some application subtract from the first installmentid instead of adding to it on each subsequent installment thus making 2,3,4 0,-1,-2 and so forth. You want to fix the issue by reverting the sequence to what should have been. If my interpretation is correct then you can do this:

```
select 
case when installmentid=1 then 1 else abs(installmentid)+2 end newinstallmentid,
amount from installments
where orderid in
(select orderid from installments group by orderid having max(installmentid)=1)
order by newinstallmentid desc
```

Example in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f71e65/5)